# Regarding doubt of order of element in a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

The problem goes as :

Let $p$ be an odd prime & $\mathbb F_{p} =\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.Show that: $x^{2}+1$ has a root in $\mathbb F_{p}$ iff $p \equiv 1 ( mod $ $4)$ .

My Solution: $\mathbb F^{*}_{p} $is the corresponding multiplicative group of order $p-1$ . Now $x^{2}+1$ has a root $t$ in $\mathbb F_{p}$ iff $\exists $ $t$ $\in \mathbb F_{p}$ satisfying: $t^{2}=-1$ . Clearly then, $t \in F^{*}_{p}$ . i.e. $ o(t) | p-1$. Now, in $F^{*}_{p}$ , the identity element is: $1 $ . & obviously $t^{4} =1$ which implies $o(t) = 4$ . i.e. $4|p-1$ . Thus, $x^{2}+1$ has a root in $\mathbb F_{p}$ iff $p \equiv 1 ( mod $ $4)$.

[Q.E.D]

Is my solution is complete?? & Is there anything to be done to take care of the "iff" mentioned in question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have proved that if the root exists, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. What remains is to show that for every such $p$, the root in $\mathbb{F}_p$ exists.

**Hint:** To prove this other implication, you can use [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: i.e. using Wilson's Theorem we can solve $x^{2} \equiv -1 ( mod $ $p )$ when $4| p-1$ ..Right??.. I mean...what I have to show for.. "..the root in $\mathbb F_{p}$ exists" ??

Comment: Also, why can't I use the argument that: the cyclic group $\mathbb F_{p}^{*}$ has an element of order $4$ IFF $4|p-1$ ??

Comment: Yes, what I meant was: the solution of the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ for $p=4k+1$ prime can be found using the Wilson's theorem. But if you take the fact that the group $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is cyclic as granted, you can use the argument about the element of order $4$ as well. Just note that this involves showing that $-1$ is the only element of order $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$

Comment: @   PavelC , Later I found elsewhere to prove the Wilson's Theorem by assuming the two results:
1) Show that: $a \in \mathbb F_{p}^{*}$ , $|a| =2$ IFF $ a= -1$ & 2) deducing that $\exists t \in \mathbb F_{p}^{*}$ such that: $t^{2} = -1$  IFF $p \equiv 1 (mod 4)$ ...... So, in the line of your thought how to prove this???

Comment: I am not sure what you want to prove. Do you want to prove the facts 1), 2) by elementary means? Or do you want to prove the Wilson's theorem using 1) and 2)? I know of a proof of Wilson's theorem which uses 1) but it does not need 2) at all.

Comment: Yess!!... I want to show Wilson's Theorem using 1) & 2) ??.... & though you told of a proof of the theorem using 1) .. Can you please tell me??

Comment: Well, the implication "$(p-1)\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$ implies $p$ is prime" is obvious, since all the numbers $1, \dots, p-1$ are necessarily coprime to $p$. Conversely, assume that $p$ is a prime. This means that all the numbers $1, \dots, p-1$ are coprime to $p$, hence (distinct) elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Then the product $(p-1)!$ is just product of all members of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, and every element which is of order different than $1$ or $2$ has an inverse distinct from itself, which is also in the product... Now just use 1) to  get the result.